# how to extract specific value in R

Tags: r, numbers, extract, digits

I'd like to extract the specific value from dataframe that I need to do data arranging in R. I can't come up with any method to use in R, so any help will be appreciated.

As an example in my dataframe looks something like this:

the raw data looks like as below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1=c('aa',438652,22, ,01),
  v2=c(343012,45, ,'pi',75),
  v3=c(56,'hi',78,670934, ),
  v4=c( ,'cc',906235,05,44))
```

However, I'd like to extract "6 digits numbers" out into another new frame
It's looked like this:

```
new <- data.frame(
  v5=c(438652,343012,670934,906235))
```

Does anyone have any ideas? That would be great appreciation !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `nchar` to count the number of characters

```
temp <- as.character(unlist(df))
data.frame(v5 = temp[nchar(temp) == 6])

#      v5
#1 438652
#2 343012
#3 670934
#4 906235
```

Comment: Perhaps it's important/useful to point out that this would also match "abcdef", i.e. 6 character long non-digit entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression

```
as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df)[grep("\\d{6}", unlist(df))]))
#[1] 438652 343012 670934 906235
```

To store in a new `data.frame`

```
data.frame(v5 = as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df)[grep("\\d{6}", unlist(df))])))
#      v5
#1 438652
#2 343012
#3 670934
#4 906235
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df, everything(), values_to = 'v5') %>%
    select(v5) %>%
    mutate(v5 = as.numeric(as.character(v5))) %>% 
    filter(nchar(v5) == 6, !is.na(v5)) 
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#      v5
#   <dbl>
#1 343012
#2 438652
#3 906235
#4 670934
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
v1 <- na.omit(as.numeric(t(df)))
v1[nchar(v1)== 6]
```